# Is Task.Run or TaskFactory.StartNew always inappropriate to use in async methods?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I've heard that the responsibility for threading should lie on the application and I shouldn't use Task.Run or maybe TaskFactory.StartNew in async methods.

However if I have a library that has methods that do quite heavy computation, then to free the threads that for example are accepting asp .net core http requests, couldn't I make the method async and make it run a long running task? Or this should be a sync method and the asp .net core application should be responsible to start the task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first, let's think why we need Asynchrony?

> Asynchrony is needed either for ***scalability*** or ***offloading***.

In case of ***Scalability***, exposing async version of that call does nothing. Because you’re typically still consuming the same amount of resources you would have if you’d invoked it synchronously, even a bit more. But, ***Scalability*** is achieved by decreasing the amount of resources you use. And you are not decreasing resources by using `Task.Run()`.

In case of ***Offloading***, you can expose async wrappers of your sync methods. Because it can be very useful for responsiveness, as it allows you to offload long-running operations to a different thread. And in that way, you are getting some benefit from that async wrapper of your method.

***Result:***

Wrapping a synchronous method with a simple asynchronous façade does not yield any scalability benefits, but yields offloading benefits. But in such cases, by ***exposing only the synchronous method***, you get some ***nice benefits***. For example:

- Surface area of your library is reduced.
- Your users will know whether there are actually scalability benefits to using exposed asynchronous APIs
- If both the synchronous method and an asynchronous wrapper around it are exposed, ***the developer is then faced with thinking they should invoke the asynchronous version for scalability(?) reasons***, but in reality will actually be hurting their throughput by paying for the additional offloading overhead without the scalability benefits.

The source is [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) by Stepen Toub. And I strongly recommend to you to read it.

***Update:***

Question in the comment:

Scalability is well explained in that article, with one example. Let's take into account `Thread.Sleep`. There are two possible ways to implement async version of that call:

```
public Task SleepAsync(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    return Task.Run(() => Sleep(millisecondsTimeout));
}
```

And another new implementation:

```
public Task SleepAsync(int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;
    var t = new Timer(delegate { tcs.TrySetResult(true); }, null, –1, -1);
    tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(t);
    t.Change(millisecondsTimeout, -1);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Both of these implementations provide the same basic behavior, both completing the returned task after the timeout has expired.  However, from a scalability perspective, the latter is much more scalable.  The former implementation consumes a thread from the thread pool for the duration of the wait time, whereas the latter simply relies on an efficient timer to signal the Task when the duration has expired.

So, in your case, just wrapping call with `Task.Run` won't be exposed for scalability, but offloading. But, user of that library is not aware of that.
User of your library, can just wrap that call with `Task.Run` himself. And I really, think he must do it.

Comment: as for scalability, are you sure? if these calls are quite rare, it is probably beneficial that I free up threads processing requests. unless you mean scalability when starting this operation many times?

Comment: @MichałZegan UPdated answer, take a lok to the `Update` part

Comment: In this specific example of mine, the first invocation of a method does heavy computation, then would probably cache it's results. and it is the method like GetSomething. The fact that it computes stuff heavily and then caches is a library implementation detail, isn't it?

Comment: @MichałZegan It depends. But, of course library can implementing caching as well. For example, in Entity Framework caching exist and it is inside EF. But, there are some cases to consider. You can take a look to the answer in that question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936788/where-to-implement-caching-class-library-or-windows-service?rq=1

Comment: It was not quite the current question. I meant that, even though offloading is a thing that should be done by the application, in this specific case after doing this computation the results would be cached. I am sure caching should belong to the library in this case. And I asked if it may be some kind of exception to the rule of not wrapping sync methods with async methods. But maybe not... Sometimes hard to say what's correct, tbh.

Comment: @MichałZegan Of course, it is not the rule. Even If you are only user of that library.  It is a matter of choice. If you read that article, at the end author gives some examples as exception to that rule which is included even inside .net framework itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answering the question (I think the other answer is good enought for that), but to add some additional advice: Becareful with using Task.Run in a library which other people can use. It can cause unexpected **Thread pool starvation** for the library users. For example a developer is using a lot of third party libraries and all of them use Task.Run() and stuff. Now the developer tries to use Task.Run in his app too, but it slows down his app, because the thread pool is already used up by the third party libraries.

When you want to parallel stuff with Parallel.ForEach it is a different issue.

Comment: I am not quite sure if the computation I meant was running long enough to warrant use of long running tasks. And they create a real thread. I'd say yes if there was blocking involved. In this case there is no blocking, and it depends on the size of the model that needs to be searched, so there is no good answer.